# Latex phi police

Tags: latex

I'm working on llncs class. I don't find which police is used to output phi symbols. So I need how to define fontfamily to \phi symbol

Comment: Perhaps [TeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) would be a better site for your question. I suggest checking their [help pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to learn more about the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to define any special font, `\phi` is displayed just fine with the default font. However be aware that you need to use it in math mode:

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\begin{document}

$\phi$

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've already known this. My originally question is mis asked. I was looking for emptyset symbol but I didn't post  as I'm new on the forum.. Thanks for the assistance

Comment: @dfm Depending on which version you want, try `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
$\varnothing$ 
$\emptyset$
\end{document}`